# How to lock window task scheduler from everyone

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler, gpedit

How can I lock windows task scheduler so that no one can access it. Even me, I wanna make it locked for everyone.
Ive seen something about `gpedit.msc` and `application lock` but it does not show up `.msc` files it just lock `exe` files.
How can I achieve this? (even without gpedit)

Answer (score 1):

With group policy (gpedit.msc), you can prevent a given *service* from running, making it disabled.  The restriction is on the service itself, not on a particular executable file.

Here are a few links which discuss that:

- [How to prevent a user from running Task Scheduler in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305612)
- [How to Disable/Enable Services (Local)](http://computerstepbystep.com/windows-xp-services-%28local%29.html)
- [Windows 7 Group Policy - Gpedit.msc](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_group_policy.htm)

You can prevent users from adding/deleting tasks (but this may not allow tasks to run as that user):

- [How to prevent a user from running Task Scheduler in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305612)

Alternatively, if you want to restrict access to specific *Control Panel* modules, you might be able to change the file-system permissions for the corresponding ".cpl" file.  Here are a few links to get started:

- [Executing Control Panel Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144191%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [What is the exhaustive list of command line shortcuts to Microsoft settings?](https://serverfault.com/questions/32589/what-is-the-exhaustive-list-of-command-line-shortcuts-to-microsoft-settings)

Comment: I dont want to disable it. I have made tasks in it. I just want to restrict access i.e. lock it.